# Does an empty commit have an empty tree in git?

Tags: git

I read this [Git Internals](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects) and a few things about tree-object are not very clear.

For intance, the current branch is `master`. The final commit object on master is an empty commit and is denoted by `cmt_end`. Given by [`git-commit-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-tree), a commit object has only one tree object. Hence, the tree object of `cmt_end` is denoted by `tree_end`.

My confusion is:

- Given by [`git-commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit), `git-commit` records changes in repository. Does this indicates that `tree_end` contains the differences between `cmt_end` and its parent? If so, `tree_end` should be an empty tree since `cmt_end` is an empty commit. If not, is it ok to have an empty tree for the empty commit?
- the `--allow-empty` option in [`git-commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit), says that an empty commit has the exact same tree as its sole parent commit. Does this indicates that the tree object of a commit records the whole working directory instead of changes when doing `git-commit`?

Comment: Note that the tree for a commit is actually built by `git write-tree`, which uses the *index* (not the working tree) to build the tree object. You can run `git ls-files --stage` to view the contents of the index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A tree object records the whole working directory. A commit object records a tree object and other entries, like the author name, the committer date and the commit message, that you can see in `git log -1 <commit> --pretty=raw` or `git cat-file -p <commit>`.

`--allow-empty` instructs `git commit` to create a commit object that reuses the tree object of its parent. If the new commit is a root commit that does not have any parent, the tree object is a special one, the empty tree, whose SHA-1 is `4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904`. The empty tree maps to an empty directory, without any sub-directories or files in it. The `empty` in `--allow-empty` means no changes have been made since the last commit or the initial state.

When an empty commit has a parent, its tree is the same with the parent's. The tree could be the empty tree or a non-empty tree, depending on the tree referenced to by the parent. When the empty commit does not have a parent, its tree is always the empty tree.

Comment: Do you have the docs to support that a tree object records the whole working directory?

Comment: @HobinC. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects and https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddeftreeobjectatreeobject. Strictly speaking, a tree object records a directory, not always the whole working directory. It might be a sub-directory of the working directory. But the whole working directory is always recorded by a tree object, which is referenced to by the commit object.

Comment: Sidenote, because it took me too long to figure it out: if you actually want to create an empty tree with said SHA-1 you can run `printf "" | git mktree`

Answer (score 1):

As you guessed at the end, the tree object in a commit actually represents the *content* of the repository at that point, not the changes relative to the previous commit. When a commit is empty, that means that the commit represents no changes relative to the previous commit, but it does *not* mean the repository contains no files as of that commit. The tree object of an empty commit will be the same as the previous commit's tree object.

Comment: Do you have the docs to support these statements, or do I miss some points in these docs given above?

Comment: @HobinC. I don't know offhand where this is described in the documentation, but I'll see what I can look up.